# Compute time between tasks

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, constraint, scheduling

I am trying to solve an optimization problem in which there is a set of tasks, $S$, where $s_i$ and $e_i$ are the starting and ending time of task $i \in S$. Each task $i $ must be done within its own time window $[a_i, b_i]$:
\begin{equation}
a_i \le s_i, \forall i \in S
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e_i \le b_i, \forall i \in S
\end{equation}

I would like to compute the time between all the pairs of tasks. That is, $s_j-e_i$ (if $i$ is scheduled before $j$) or $s_i-e_j$ (if $j$ is scheduled before $i$).

The objective is to minimize the times between all the pairs of tasks. How can I define it?

Comment: Do you have a single resource or multiple ones? Is there any relationship between the tasks?

Comment: Only one resource is considered. Furthermore, tasks are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is the following: Introduce variable $t_{ij}$ that is the time between tasks $i$ and $j$. This variable is only defined for once per pair $ij$, therefore the $j >i$. Then, you can write:

\begin{align}
\
& \min \sum_{i \in S}\sum_{j \in S, j>i} t_{ij}  \; \\
\end{align}

and adding the following two constraints:

\begin{align}
& s_j - e_i \leq t_{ij} & \forall i,j \in S, j>i \tag1 \\ 
& s_i - e_j \leq t_{ij} & \forall i,j \in S, j>i \tag2 \\  
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It is great :)